# Mocha -chai coverage Unknown

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, code-coverage, chai

Hi all I am trying to get the mocha chai Unit test coverage report.

I am getting the test result passed.

Also generated the coverage as html but, it showing Unknown. Please see below image .

[image]

`Package.json` added the below config in script.

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "test-with-coverage": "nyc --reporter=html mocha"
  },
```

And using the below command for run the test.

```
npm run test-with-coverage
```

**Edit:**
When change report as text , getting the below report in terminal.

```
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with the below command,

```
nyc -x \"**/tests/**\" --reporter=cobertura --reporter=html mocha 'your test folder path'
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am new to node js and unit testing. Could you please explain / any reference to describe this.

Comment: What was the issue ?

Comment: You had not mentioned your test folder path for mocha to understand where it should look for test files.